# While awaiting my Spanish residence card, can I travel through the Schengen area?

Tags: working-visas, residence-permits

I am a non-EU citizen on a Spanish work visa at the moment, and have a 1-2 month wait before receiving my residence card from the local police station.

During this period, am I allowed to leave and re-enter Spain as long as I stay within the Schengen area?

Comment: What's your citizenship?

Comment: United States Citizen

Comment: Is the visa that you used to enter Spain still valid?  Do you have a receipt for your residence permit application or another document showing that you are waiting for the permit?